# Finding average time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

I have an integer array, and some x integer value. I need to loop over the array comparing if the current array value is equal to x. If so, the loop breaks.

The worst-case time complexity is W(n) = n (searched element is at the end of the array)
The best-case time complexity is B(n) = 1 (searched element is at the beginning of the array)
My question is - how do I find the average-case time complexity here?

As far as I know I have two possible cases - the element can be found in the array, and the element is not in there. But what's next? Do I have to count some probabilities? Or just simply say A(n) = n/2? What about the second case?

Comment: If you write `A(n) = n/2`  you are assuming that `x` can be in any position with equal probability `1/n` (or not in the array). If you don't know where the array came from, it may be a safe assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Average-case complexity when the element is in the array:

```
A(n) = n / 2
```

Average-case complexity when the element is not in the array:

```
A(n) = n
```

If the probability that the element is in the array is `0 <= p <= 1`,
then your average case complexity is:

```
A(n) = p * (n / 2) + (1 - p) * n
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit how did you get the last formula?

Comment: if you have probability p=0.4 that a item is in the array, you will find it 0.4 (40%) of the time and 1-0.4 (60%) it will not be found. If you will find it, on average you will find it halfway, if you don't find it you need to iterate the entire array to know. 40% of the time halfway and 60% of the time entirely results in 0.4*(n/2)+0.6*n elements searched on average.

Comment: @Enigma That's more about average case processing time, not so much about complexity. The complexity question is more along the lines of "If my current algorithm, given data of size N, has an average time of x, then what is the expected average time if I give it 2*N data? Is it 2*x (which would be O(n)), or x^2 or 10^x or ...?"

Answer (score 1):

Chances are incredibly high that this prompt wants you to use Big-O notation (you can look this up yourself).

The asymptotic average-case complexity when the element is or is not in the array is still O(n), because the /2 is a "constant factor" that is abstracted out of Big-O notation.

My conjecture is further given credence by the fact that you're not told how much time it takes to increment an index or compare two elements. You're already assuming that several things are "acceptable constants", so a /2 here or there does not change the asymptotic time complexity you are concerned with at all.